# E5013 значение типа A::B* нельзя присвоить сущности типа B*

Tags: c++, классы, указатели, вложенные-классы

Изучаю плюсы, сейчас разбираюсь с классами. Имеется вложенный, в `класс A`, `класс B`. Указатель типа `B` объявляется в приват поле `класса A` и в конструкторе `класса A` инициализируется. Компилятор выдает такую ошибку.

> E5013 значение типа A::B* нельзя присвоить сущности типа B*.

A.h

```
#pragma once

class B;

class A
{
public:
    A();

private:

    B* pt_b;
   
    class B
    {
    public:

        B(int s) :
            a(s)
        {}

        B();

        void set_a(int e) { a = e; };

    private:
        int a, b, c;
    };
};
```

A.cpp

```
#include "A.h"

A::A()
{
    pt_b = new B(5);
    this->pt_b.set_a(1);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Собственно, выбросьте предварительное объявление — у вас есть `A::B`, а не `B`. Далее, перенесите объявление `B* pt_b;` *после* объявления класса `A::B`. Ну, и правильно используйте объявленное:

```
pt_b = new A::B(5);
this->pt_b->set_a(1);
```